# How to show UIViewController in other UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

This is typical question and possibly duplicated, but..

There is iPad app which has `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. I have created a button on navigationBar which must show **appinfoViewController**.

When I present it navigationBar and tabTab are still available to tap. But I would like to show  **appinfoViewController** to full app's main screen size (like modal)

This is my code:

```
- (void)showInfo
{
AboutViewController *about = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
[about.view setFrame: self.view.frame];
[about.view setAlpha:0.0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [about.view setAlpha:1.0];

                     [self.view addSubview:about.view];
                     [self addChildViewController:about];
                     [about didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
}
```

How to present **appinfoViewController** to full screen?

May be it's possible to present it modally but without BLACK background?

Comment: addSubview is different than addChildViewController. I mean : you can instantiate a controller, and add its view (only the view) in another controller. The first controller still existing and controlling your view, even if it is not in its original controller view hierarchy. But for a modal presentation, you can try : `[self presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:nil]`

Comment: Did you tried `presentViewController` for presenting a viewcontroller as modal?

Comment: yes, but `presentViewController` has a black background.. but I need transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, using

```
[self presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:nil]
```

would get rid of the nav bar and the tab bar. If you need to keep them, you need to use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:about animated:YES];
```

EDIT:

In order to have the user interaction disabled everywhere except for your about view, it's slightly trickier: first off, you need to have all of your UI elements embedded in a view that is not the main view of your presenting view controller.

Let's say you have only a button (the "show about" button), you wouldn't just place it in your main view, but you would use another view (let's call it "outer view") that is just as big as the view controller's view and where you place the button (along with any other ui element you might have). You also need an outlet to this outer view. Then write a method such as:

```
-(void)userInteractionEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{   
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = enabled;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = enabled;
    self.outerView.userInteractionEnabled = enabled;
}
```

Alternatively you could simply disable every "interactive" outlet instead of outerView. So if, for example, you have 2 textviews, 3 buttons and one UIPickerView, you would set `userInteractionEnabled = enabled` for each of those outlets (instead of doing it only for the parent view).

Now, in your showInfo method you can have:

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200); //Use whatever origin and size you need
 about.view.frame = frame;
 [self.view addSubview:about.view];
 [self userInteractionEnabled:NO]
```

And in your btnClose method you can just put:

```
[about.view removeFromSuperview];
[self userInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

I hope this helps, let me know if this is what you needed!

P.S. Maybe you're already aware of this, but there is a class `UIPopoverController`, only available for iPad's apps, that would pretty much do all of this for you. You can find a tutorial on how to use it [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial).

Comment: the first closes all around with black background (

Comment: what do you mean with closes all around?

Comment: if I use `[self presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:nil]` my view (with size 300x200) appears in "parentView" but all around 300x200 is black!

Comment: Ok i think i understand now what you want to do. You would like this about view to be on top of the other one, and still be able to see it around this 300x200 frame?

Comment: yes (sorry for my english) ))) and neither (navigationBar or tabBar) should not be available for tap

Comment: ok, and how do you want to let the user dismiss this About view controller?

Comment: by tapping on some "btnClose" )

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    AboutViewController *about = (AboutViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"about"];
```

[self.navigationController pushViewController:about animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You can add viewcontroller view layer directly to presenting viewcontroller view.

Code should be look like --

```
AboutViewController *about = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
[about.view setFrame: self.view.bound];
[about.view setAlpha:0.0];
[self.view addSubview:about.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [about.view setAlpha:1.0];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```